# AngularJS route resolve when calling controller using ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

Please see my plunkr here

https://plnkr.co/edit/hk7Z0jMwOfoUwJZ98F7a?p=preview

In my app.js I have two controllers and a routeprovider with a resolve for TestController

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);


app.controller('DefaultController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.welcome = "Hello World";  
}]);

app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'context', '$routeParams', function($scope, context, $routeParams){
  $scope.text = "TestController loaded!"  
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/test1',{
      templateUrl: 'test1.html',
      controller: 'TestController',
      resolve: {
        context: function(){return 'test';}
      }
    })
}])
```

In my html, I have an ng-include which should also load test.html in the default view

```
 <body ng-controller="DefaultController">
    <h1>{{welcome}}</h1>

    <div ng-include="'test.html'" ng-controller='TestController'></div>


  </body>
```

I cannot take the resolve out of the routeProvider as I still need it to when the user goes to '../test'

Is there any way I can resolve contextProvider from the ng-include?

or is there better ways to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. What is the state `/test` since you defined `/test` in the router config. If both are different, then when does it invokes?

Comment: sorry I meant the state /test in the router config is for when the user navigates to for example  http://myUrl.com/#/test.

Comment: so essentially there I want to ways to get to this page. One is through the route config and the other one as a partial view on another page. I hope I am making this clear. I'm so bad at explaining something.

Answer (score 2):

Create a factory/service and use that:

```
app.factory('fooResolver', function() {
    return {
        resolveMe: function() {
            return 'test';
        }
    }
});
```

Now, use this in your router config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
  $routeProvider.
    when('/test1',{
      templateUrl: 'test1.html',
      controller: 'TestController',
      resolve: {
        context: function(fooResolver) {
             return fooResolver.resolveMe();
        }
      }
    })
}])
```

And do the same in your controller:

```
app.controller('TestController', ['$scope', 'fooResolver', '$routeParams', function($scope, fooResolver, $routeParams){
  $scope.text = "TestController loaded!"
  var context = fooResolver.resolveMe();
}]);
```